# Why is spring Prometheus metrics not showing actual data in json?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus

I need my custom metrics from `@Service` class to display. I successfully displayed metric name. But I am unable to display the corresponding value. I used builder in Constructor and then regular `increment()` function. There is no value. Not even 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
Counter timeElapsedHandleError = Counter.builder("time_handle_error”).description("Time in ms of run fnc handleError").register(registry);

timeElapsedHandleError.increment();
```

I successfully incremented value of counter within the class but I am unable to export it.

---

So i resolved the issue. The problem was between pc and the chair. The metrics were just hidden under the name of the metric in URL. So for example "time_handle_error“ was showing in localhost:port/actuator/metrics (in the list), but the actual values of this metric was on localhost:port/actuator/metrics/time_handle_error.